# Guzzle 7 - 403 Forbidden (works fine with CURL)

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

UPDATE: it seems that the user-agent isn't the only header some hosts require to serve HTML, I also had to add the 'accepts' header, and in the end, this solved the problem for me with many hosts:

```
  $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://acme.com', ['headers' => ['user-agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36',
'accept'=> 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
        ]]);
```

I'm trying to use Guzzle to retrieve some websites but receiving a 403 forbidden error (when they work fine in a browser), I suspect this is down to non-standard User-Agents being forbidden by the host.  To get around this, I am trying to set the User-Agent in Guzzle to mimic a browser but I can't find any method that actually works.  I can browse the website and use WGET and CURL -L to download the HTML with no problems so the issue seems to be with Guzzle.

I've tried the following:

```
    $client = new Client(['allow_redirects' => ['track_redirects' => true]]);
    $client->setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.62 Safari/537.36");
    $response = $client->get($domain_name);
```

**Weirdly this ^ one results in an error that seems to say Guzzle is trying to browse to the User-Agent value: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: Mozilla (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for Mozilla/5.0%20(Windows%20NT%206.2;%20WOW64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like**

```
    $domain_name = 'http://www.' . $domain_name;
    $client = new Client(['headers' => ['User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36']]);
    $response = $client->get($domain_name);
```

**^Results in a "Client error: `GET http://www.xxx.co.uk` resulted in a `403 Forbidden'" error**

```
    $domain_name = 'http://www.' . $domain_name;
    $client = new Client(['allow_redirects' => ['track_redirects' => true]]);
    $client->setServerParameter('user-agent', "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36");
    $response = $client->get($domain_name);
```

**^Results in a "Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, string given" error**

```
    $domain_name = 'http://www.' . $domain_name;
    $client = new Client(['allow_redirects' => ['track_redirects' => true]]);
    $client->setHeader("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36");
    $response = $client->get($domain_name);
```

**^ Also results in a "Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, string given" error**

Any suggestions?  I've gone down a rabbit hole here I think!

I'm wondering if something else is happening here because as I understand it, Guzzle is just a wrapper for CURL and CURL can fetch the same web page, from the same IP with no problem.

Comment: use [on_stats](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#on-stats) as guzzle options, you will be able to see what user agent is seen, when you call `$stats->getHandlerStats()`, at first you should check after applying the first method the proper user-agent header is sent or not

Comment: Thanks Bhucho, I tried this and unfortunately still get the 403 error and can't see any header data (as the exception kills it).  I'm wondering if something else is going on here because as I understand it, Guzzle is just a wrapper for CURL and CURL can fetch the same web page, from the same IP with no problem.

Comment: it would still have error I told to use stats to help in debugging at the time of sending requests getHandlerStats() provides stats of all the details in an array, also guzzle can use Curl, but it is not a wrapper guzzle is a http client not a curl client, it can work even without curl

Comment: use `['debug' => true]` it will also tell the name of user-client when sending requests

Comment: have a look at this upgrade https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#client . As per this upgrade setUserAgent() has been removed.

Comment: Your second method `$client = new Client(['headers' => ['User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36']]);` should give you the user agent as mozilla, but if it is still giving 403 then the error seems to be not due to user-agent

Comment: Thanks bhuho, in the end it turns out I also needed to add the accept header - seems many webservers want that or they kick you back!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the user-agent isn't the only header some hosts require to serve HTML, I also had to add the 'accepts' header, in the end this solved the problem for me with many hosts:

```php
$response = $client->request('GET', 'http://acme.com', [
  'headers' => [
    'user-agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36',
    'accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
  ]
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

For those who are still struggling with this can add user-agent header -

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'headers' => [
        'User-Agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    ]
]);
```

Hope this will solve the problem