# Call api in local with Guzzle or Symfony httpClient

Tags: symfony, guzzle

I got a problem that I don't undesrstand, I hope have  the help here.
So, I explain you, I want to request "GET" infos from an api in local, with postman or from browser these work well.
But from in my code I use guzzlehttp client or symfony httpclient for call to api these give me error 400 (HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request returned). I don't get it why, I need the help, thank  in advance.
I did exactly like explain from symfony doc and guzzle doc too, but nothing good.

```
//in my class
private $symfonyDocs;
public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $symfonyDocs) //HttpClientInterface injection
{
   $this->symfonyDocs = $symfonyDocs;
}

// in my function
$response = $this->symfonyDocs->request(
       'GET',
       'http://localhost:8080/county'
);
dd($response->getContent()); //just see response content
```

//error picture
[with symfony client, I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQo73.png)

//error picture 2
[with guzzle client, I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrQFf.png)

Note:
in my own computer all work good with another api in local, but in my company's computer that's not the case.

Comment: I just create a new api with only entity person, from postman or browser these work well, but guzzle or symfony client, I alwayse get error HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request returned for "http://localhost:8080/persons". that crazy, i don't understand what happens

Comment: You can check the profiler, http://localhost:8080/_profiler, and search for your /county request. There should be more info why it is returning a 400 error.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, try to apply accept, content-type & user agent header same as the browser, try user-agent last as it should least affect

Comment: take a bit help from this question [Guzzle 7 - 403 Forbidden (works fine with CURL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65915286/guzzle-7-403-forbidden-works-fine-with-curl)

Comment: With HttpClient component, you can't call localhost routes, it's only for external calls. If your route return en entity, inject EntityManager and retrieve your entity. If not, inject service who's return what you need.
Reserve you API call only if you need to call an external API

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the same problem